# How to add a value to a key in dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

My question is that I want to make a program that displays names and scores. I want to get user input for a number and a name. If the name is in the dictionary, then it will append the value to the key but if it isn't, it will make a new key value pair. I have tried for hours but can't seem to do it.

```
class_1 = {'Farid':9, 'Manraj':5, 'Andy':7, 'Sajid':3}

score=int(input("Enter a number"))
name=input("What is your name?")

if name in class_1.key():
    class_1[name]=score
else:
    class_1[name]=score
```

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or Python 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use `key()`. Just do:

```
if name in class_1:
```

And you are not really appending the new score to the existing one. You should do something like that:

```
class_1[name]+=score
```

So that you have

```
score=int(raw_input("Enter a number: "))
name=raw_input("What is your name?: ")

if name in class_1:
    class_1[name]+=score
else:
    class_1[name]=score
```

**EDIT**: If you want to append the new score to the old one and have both of the separately, you should define your dictionary values as list:

```
class_1 = {'Farid':[9], 'Manraj':[5], 'Andy':[7], 'Sajid':[3]}
```

And then, to append new score:

```
if name in class_1:
    class_1[name].append(score)
```

Comment: i edited the program so that it asks for the name and score but now if the name is in the dictionary, it adds it to the previous score. Is there a possible way to have them as two seperate integers

Comment: If I understood correctly, you wanted to **append** the value. Or did you mean not as an arithmetic append but rather as a list append?

Comment: Thanks alot! One slight thing though, why is it that when i enter farid, it is a different key to Farid?

Comment: @student1999 That's because Python Dictionary keys are case sensitive. If you want to make sure that no matter what case will be used the key will be found, you can convert all new names to lower case before comparing the values.

Comment: Eugene, is there a way to work out an average from the values. So i want to create a seperate dictionary, using the same keys but instead of multiple values, i want just an average of the scores

Comment: @student1999 Create a new dictionary just as before and instead of appending a number as a value, append the sum of the values of a certain key divided by the length of the list.